# Sympy expression in odeint() gives derivation error

Tags: python, scipy, sympy, ode, derivative

I'm trying to automatise several processes, like generating ODEs from Lagrangians with Sympy and doing numerical integration on them with Numpy and Scipy. **Full code at the end.** As result of generating the ODEs with `solve()` I get a dictionary with Sympy expressions like the following:

```
{Derivative(lambda1(t), t): (y(t) + 1)/(x(t)*y(t)),
 Derivative(z(t), t): x(t),
 Derivative(x(t), t): y(t)*z(t),
 Derivative(y(t), t): -x(t)*z(t)
 }
```

then from this I would like to integrate the differential equation system with `odeint()` from Scipy. For this I would need to extract the expressions (with `lambdify` for example) from the dictionary inside a `def Field(Q,t):`, to introduce as  `odeint(Field,Q_0,t_array)`. Here is where I run with difficulties:

I first tried

```
def Equ2(nQ,t,Q,Field):
x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
dQ =[]
for f in Q:
    dQ.append(lambdify(Q, Field[f.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1))
return dQ[0:len(nQ)]
```

but it can't go to `odeint()` as it it takes fields with 2 arguments, and I tried to pass it in the optional `arga=()` of `odeint()`, giving me  a (long) error:

```
ValueError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-63f086b8a252> in Equ2(nQ, t, Q, Field)
      20     dQ =[]
      21     for f in Q:
 ---> 22         dQ.append(lambdify(Q, Field[f.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1))
      23     return dQ[0:len(Q)-1]

[...]
ValueError: 
Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt 14.0430379424125.
```

So I tried essentially the same but without the loops,

```
def Equ1(nQ,t):
x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
dx = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[x.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
dy = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[y.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
dz = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[z.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
dlam = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[lam[0].diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
return [dx,dy,dz]
```

and have the (I think) same problem:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-63f086b8a252> in Equ1(nQ, t)
      9 def Equ1(nQ,t):
     10     x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
---> 11     dx = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[x.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
     12     dy = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[y.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
     13     dz = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[z.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)

[...]
ValueError: 
Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt 17.6326726993661.
```

If I try simply:

```
def Equ0(nQ,t):
x,y,z,lamb = nQ
dx = y*z
dy = -x*z
dz = x
dlam = (y+1.)/(x*y)
return [dx,dy,dz]
```

the integration works just fine. Also if I call the `EquX()` functions with similar arguments that it would take inside `odeint()` they work just fine.

**FULL CODE**

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.mechanics import dynamicsymbols
from numpy import linspace, sin, cos
from scipy.integrate import odeint

t = Symbol('t')
x = Function('x')(t)
y = Function('y')(t)
z = Function('z')(t)

lam = dynamicsymbols('lambda1:{0}'.format(5))
f = x.diff(t)- y*z
eq = Matrix([x.diff(t) - lam[0].diff(t)*y*x*z+z,
         y.diff(t) +x*z,
         z.diff(t)-x
        ])

field = solve(list(eq)+[f],[x.diff(t),y.diff(t),z.diff(t),lam[0].diff(t)])


def Equ0(nQ,t):
    x,y,z,lamb = nQ
    dx = y*z
    dy = -x*z
    dz = x
    dlam = (y+1.)/(x*y)
    return [dx,dy,dz]

def Equ1(nQ,t):
    x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
    dx = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[x.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
    dy = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[y.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
    dz = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[z.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
    dlam = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[lam[0].diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
    return [dx,dy,dz]


def Equ2(nQ,t,Q,Field):
    x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
    dQ =[]
    for f in Q:
        dQ.append(lambdify(Q, Field[f.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1))
    return dQ[0:len(Q)-1]

q = [x,y,z,lam[0]]
nq = [1,2,3,4]
time=linspace(0,10,10)

### This line works just fine:
print Equ0(nq,t), Equ1(nq,t), Equ2(nq,t,q,field) #They give the same output 

sol0 = odeint(Equ0,nq,time)
sol1 = odeint(Equ1,nq,time) #Errors here
sol2 = odeint(Equ2,nq,time,args=(q,field)) #And here
```

Lastly the full error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-20-63f086b8a252> in Equ1(nQ, t)
  9 def Equ1(nQ,t):
 10     x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
 ---> 11     dx = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[x.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
 12     dy = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[y.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
 13     dz = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[z.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
2864         new_symbols = list(map(sympify, symbols))  # e.g. x, 2, y, z---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-63f086b8a252> in Equ1(nQ, t)
  9 def Equ1(nQ,t):
 10     x1,y1,z1,lamb1 = nQ
 ---> 11     dx = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[x.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
 12     dy = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[y.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)
 13     dz = lambdify((x,y,z,lam[0]), field[z.diff(t)],'numpy' )(x1,y1,z1,lamb1)

  /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/expr.pyc in diff(self, *symbols, **assumptions)
  2864         new_symbols = list(map(sympify, symbols))  # e.g. x, 2, y, z
2865         assumptions.setdefault("evaluate", True)
---> 2866         return Derivative(self, *new_symbols, **assumptions)
2867 
2868     ###########################################################################

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.pyc in __new__(cls, expr, *variables, **assumptions)
1068                 ordinal = 'st' if last_digit == 1 else 'nd' if last_digit == 2 else 'rd' if last_digit == 3 else 'th'
1069                 raise ValueError(filldedent('''
---> 1070                 Can\'t calculate %s%s derivative wrt %s.''' % (count, ordinal, v)))
1071 
1072             if all_zero and not count == 0:

ValueError: 
Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt 0.0.

2865         assumptions.setdefault("evaluate", True)
---> 2866         return Derivative(self, *new_symbols, **assumptions)
2867 
2868     ###########################################################################

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/core/function.pyc in __new__(cls, expr, *variables, **assumptions)
1068                 ordinal = 'st' if last_digit == 1 else 'nd' if last_digit == 2 else 'rd' if last_digit == 3 else 'th'
1069                 raise ValueError(filldedent('''
---> 1070                 Can\'t calculate %s%s derivative wrt %s.''' % (count, ordinal, v)))
1071 
1072             if all_zero and not count == 0:

ValueError: 
Can't calculate 1st derivative wrt 0.0.
```

**TL;DR** Some derivation Error appears inside odeint() that I cant reproduce outside odeint() with custom made functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `t` as symbol you should avoid declaring `t` as floating point number in the function declaration. Try replacing the floating point `t` with another name, `s` or `tt` or ...